# "to offer" in Japanese?

Tags: words, usage

Using a dictionary to learn Japanese turned out to be more difficult than expected.

I wanted to say "I offered him a haircut but he refused." and "I offered him a beer." and "I offered him a ride."

Since I didn't know "to offer" in Japanese I tried to look it up but there seem to be many different ways of saying it.

> Please could someone help me understand the correct usage of the
>   following words and also tell me which to use in the above sentences?

So I got the following words which all seem to mean "to offer":

(1) オファーする

(2) 申し入れする

(3) 提供する

Personally, at a first attempt, I'd go for 提供する but I have a feeling the correct translation might turn out to be something that's not even on the list above.

Comment: Have you looked at 申し出る？

Comment: Here are your three translations: "カットしたろか言うて断れてん", "ビールを奢った", "送ってやった"。

Comment: @oldergod なんで関西弁？(It's [断]{ことわ}られてん not [断]{ことわ}れてん, by the way.)

Comment: @Choko thank you. I always mess up on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say

「彼に散髪{さんぱつ}しようと提案{ていあん}したが断{ことわ}られた」for "I offered him a haircut but he refused."

「彼にビールを一杯{いっぱい}勧{すす}めた」for "I offered him a beer."

「車に同乗{どうじょう}するよう彼を誘{さそ}った」for "I offered him a ride."

Note that the above is just one of many possibilities.

> the correct usage of the following

I am not sure if I can offer (no pun intended) you "correct usage" of the words. My impression is:

(1) オファーする  sounds stilted, as "オファー" is a transliteration of "offer".

(2) 申し入れする sounds more of "claiming" and "requesting" than "offering".

(3) 提供する　　is a possible translation of "to offer". Usage examples coming into my mind include

"情報を提供する"　to offer (relevant) information

and

"資金を提供する"　 to offer a budgetary contribution

BTW

> Using a dictionary to learn Japanese turned out to be more difficult than expected.

is true, but I suspect that can be said for any languages.

Comment: Is this a bad answer? Just curious why it was downvoted. I can't tell as I'm not a native speaker. Are you a native speaker, eltonjohn?

Comment: @Rudy the Reindeer: I really would like to know why I got downvoted (by at least two blokes / hens) too. BTW, I am a native speaker.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know too, so I gave you an upvote. Maybe they are writing other answers right now, we'll see.

Comment: @ Kaizokugari: Thank you very much indeed for your support. And, yes, let's see what happens.

Comment: @Rudy the Reindeer It's a good answer.  I'm not native but I have L1/N1.  "Offer" is one of those situational words where there's not a 1 to 1 mapping to English.  If i hear it in katakana, I assume someone got a job offer from a company.

Comment: Thank you, eltonjohn, your answer is very helpful to me!